# gulp.src(globs) From a Variable Array

Tags: arrays, variables, gulp, global-variables

How can a variable (array) be used in `gulp.src(globs)`?

I have several Gulp tasks that use the same "group" of files but I do not know how to DRY the tasks to use the variable passed into the globs.

```js
. . .
var configDir   = '../private/app/_config/',
    configFiles = [
        configDir + 'categories.yaml',
        configDir + 'params.yaml',
        configDir + 'taxonomies.yaml'
    ];

// Merge development config yaml(s)
gulp.task('yaml_merge-dev', function() {
  return gulp.src([
        'config.root.yaml',
        configDir + 'site.dev.yaml',
        configFiles
      ])
    .pipe(yamlMerge('config.dev.yaml'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../'));
});

// Merge production config yaml(s)
gulp.task('yaml_merge-prod', function() {
  return gulp.src([
        'config.root.yaml',
        configDir + 'site.prod.yaml',
        configFiles
      ])
    .pipe(yamlMerge('config.prod.yaml'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../'));
})
. . . // etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gulp.src()` only accepts one flat array of files, not nested arrays. That means you have to add all the files in `configFiles` to the array that you pass to `gulp.src()`.

Since gulp is just JavaScript, you can use any of the many possible ways that you can combine arrays in JavaScript. In your case  [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) is probably the most appropriate:

```
gulp.task('yaml_merge-dev', function() {
  return gulp.src([
    'config.root.yaml',
    configDir + 'site.dev.yaml'
  ].concat(configFiles))
  .pipe(yamlMerge('config.dev.yaml'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('../'));
});
```

Comment: Thx - I + it too because I didn't think of `concat`.  Thnx again.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to want to **DRY** your tasks.

Using [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs), you can narrow down your code to a single task that uses command line arguments.

**Run:**

```
npm install --save-dev yargs
```

**Javascript**

```
. . . 
// Require yargs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs
var args = require('yargs').argv;

// Site file based on argument
var siteFile = args.release? 'site.prod.yaml' : 'site.dev.yaml';

// Merge config file based on argument
var yamlMergeConfig = args.release? 'config.prod.yaml' : 'config.dev.yaml';

// Single declatations for readibility
var configDir = '../private/app/_config/';

// Your config files in a single glob
var configFiles = [
        configDir + 'categories.yaml',
        configDir + 'params.yaml',
        configDir + 'taxonomies.yaml'
        configDir + siteFile
    ];

gulp.task('yaml_merge', function() {
  /// <summary>
  /// Merge development or production config yaml(s)
  /// gulp yaml_merge             : deploys the development build
  /// gulp yaml_merge --release   : deploys the release build
  /// </summary>
  return gulp.src(configFiles)
    .pipe(yamlMerge(yamlMergeConfig))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../'));
});
. . . // etc.
```

Comment: I'd give you more points if I could but Sven's answer was within the scope of the question. However your answer is a better answer due to the fact you went beyond to actually 'DRY'n' the task.  I'm am sure you gain points over time.

Comment: Thanks @CelticParser. I'm actually more interested in exchanging ideas than getting points, so no worries. Based on the setup of your question and the ellipses I assumed you have more tasks that depend on whether the build is for development or release as we all do. So try and play around with yargs and you'll get a lot more from gulp.

Comment: Awesome - You are right-on! I did implement your method with some tweeks. I'm always learning on a (very) sharp curve and this is a big help. Thnx again.

Comment: You are very welcome. I've tried to answer quite a few gulp questions so check out some of them on my profile. I generally recommend using **bower** to manage client dependencies and **npm** for server dependencies. If you don't already know about them you may be interested in some of these: [gulp-load-plugins](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-load-plugins), [wiredep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wiredep), [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject), [gulp-useref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref) to automatically update dependencies.